# Received memory warning. Level=1 in iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, memory-leaks, warnings, didreceivememorywarning

Regarding this question I had research lot and got the different suggestion, but non of these 100% works, I have 15 view Controllers and I am releasing all unnecessary objects, variables and dealloc images Data and everything that is unnecessary. My app is not going to crash but got the Received memory warning. Level=1 warning and screens suddenly goes black.

More over I got the below warning after surfing the app for 10-15 minutes if no application is running in back ground. IF More applications are running in background in ipad than i got the error in just 5 mins of surfing the app.

I had tried the below suggestion From others Answers for this type of questions

1. dealloc and release the objects in `- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning` Function
2. Change the resolution of MKMapView

Please any one have other solution for this issue than please tell.

Thanx in Advance..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use memory profiler (allocations instrument) in order to see which parts of your code allocates how much memory. Even more with the profiler you can see the exact point where your app gets that memory warning.

Answer (score 0):

In IOS SDK 6, you need to clear all IBOutlets in Received memory warning function. its due to app using more memory or memory leak.

thanks